# Tensorflow C Resize changing properties wrong

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow with the compiled library.

I started by adapting the [label image example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc). I am reading a raw file in the adapted `ReadTensorFromImageFile`. Here, I am reading the file with a size of `256 x 256` and resizing and reshaping it to a final tensor shape of `[1, 256, 256, 1]`. See code below.

```c
Status ReadTensorFromImageFile(const string& file_name, const int input_height,
                               const int input_width,
                               std::vector<Tensor>* out_tensors) {
  auto root = tensorflow::Scope::NewRootScope();
  using namespace ::tensorflow::ops;  // NOLINT(build/namespaces)

  string input_name = "file_reader";
  string output_name = "resized";

  // read file_name into a tensor named input
  Tensor input(tensorflow::DT_STRING, tensorflow::TensorShape());
  TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(
      ReadEntireFile(tensorflow::Env::Default(), file_name, &input));

  // use a placeholder to read input data
  auto file_reader =
      Placeholder(root.WithOpName("input"), tensorflow::DataType::DT_STRING);

  std::vector<std::pair<string, tensorflow::Tensor>> inputs = {
      {"input", input},
  };

  // Now try to figure out what kind of file it is and decode it.
  tensorflow::Output image_reader;
  if (tensorflow::str_util::EndsWith(file_name, ".raw")) {
    image_reader = DecodeRaw(root.WithOpName("raw_reader"), file_reader,
                             tensorflow::DT_FLOAT);
  } else {
    // Assume if it's neither a PNG nor a GIF then it must be a JPEG.
    return tensorflow::errors::NotFound(
      "No decoder found for file ", file_name);
  }
  // Now cast the image data to float so we can do normal math on it.
  auto float_caster =
      Cast(root.WithOpName("float_caster"), image_reader, tensorflow::DT_FLOAT);

  auto resha = Reshape(root.WithOpName("foo"), float_caster, Const(root, {1, 512, 512, 1}));

  auto resized = ResizeBilinear(
      root, resha,
      Const(root.WithOpName(output_name), {input_height, input_width}));

  tensorflow::GraphDef graph;
  TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(root.ToGraphDef(&graph));

  std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session> session(
      tensorflow::NewSession(tensorflow::SessionOptions()));
  TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(session->Create(graph));
  TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(session->Run({inputs}, {output_name}, {}, out_tensors));
  return Status::OK();
}
```

The code to call this function looks like

```
  std::vector<Tensor> resized_tensors;
  Status read_tensor_status =
      ReadTensorFromImageFile(image, 256, 256, &resized_tensors);
  if (!read_tensor_status.ok()) {
    LOG(ERROR) << read_tensor_status;
    return -1;
  }
  const Tensor& resized_tensor = resized_tensors[0];
  LOG(ERROR) << resized_tensor.DebugString();
```

The issue here is, the shaping into a format of `[1, 512, 512, 1]` works fine and the debug output (`DebugString()`) looks as expected: `Tensor<type: float shape: [1,512,512,1] values: [[[1][1][1]]]...>`.

But if I want to resize that image, as I did in that function, my output gets really weird: `Tensor<type: int32 shape: [2] values: 256 256>`. The datatype, size and content is off to the expected.

I tried already several combinations with the reshape and resize parameters, but nothing seems to work out. Do you have an idea how I could solve this issue or what I am doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know much about Tensorflow but Here, you're giving a vector of size 2 with `{input_height, input_width}`, so maybe try with `{1, input_height, input_width, 1}`

Comment: Thats what I did as well. Tried already several combinations.